# Magento search not working after Reindexing

Tags: attributes, database, catalogsearch, reindex

I have recently started working on Magento. 
I had to fix search issue wherein the products were not displayed on the frontend for some values of attribute "brand" even if the products exist for that brand in the database.

So i did Re indexing and cleared the cache, but these steps broke up my full search. i.e. full search functionality stopped working and also listing of products by categories. I did re indexing and cache clear again but it could not fix the issue.

I was able to fix the listing by categories issue when i found out that "catalog_product_index_price" was empty after re indexing. I repopulated the table with my backup data. 
But I'm still  not able to fix the search.Can anyone tell me how i can fix this.
What database tables are related to search?? and  where the query is generated??

Answer (score 1):

The query is generated in Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext and the table is catalogsearch_fulltext if you are using default magento search. However I would advice you to try and fix your indexing issue instead of putting back a backup. Putting back the backup only solves your problem untill the next reindex. Did you add some custom code or something?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Firstly, there is no custom coding for the indexer and listing by attributes. There are lots of products on the website and the indexing was 

done using ssh. Is large number of products reason for indexing failure?? Data is present in "catalogsearch_fulltext" but there was some problem with store_id so 

"catalogsearch_results" was not populating. But not sure why the products are not loaded still even after fixing :(